# side by side divs in full width

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have problems to place N divs side by side with full browser width

I want like this. when you resize browser space between divs must stay same and divs must resize in width.

```
|div| |div| |div|

|  div  | |  div  | |  div  |
```

Comment: What browser level do you have to support?

Comment: Use 960.gs, bootstrap, or some other scaffolding. Both of those 2 have the ability to customize the column and gutter widths before downloading your customized version. They also both support fluid width layouts.

Comment: +1 for 960.gs, it's simple to use

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use percentages:

```
div.mydiv {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you do this, be careful with padding: that adds to a `div`'s width, possibly causing overflow. This can be fixed if you support only IE >=8, by doing

```
div.mydiv {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* OMG why doesn't Firefox support this yet */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari below 5.1, including 5 */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And if you do that, there's even one more possible problem: space between the `div`s. This occurs because you have empty text nodes in between them, and `display: inline-block` thinks that's OK: elements laid out in an `inline`-type fashion can be interspersed with blank text nodes. To fix this, there's a pretty bad hack:

```
div.containerOfAllTheDivs {
    font-size: 0;
}
div.mydiv {
    font-size: 12px; /* or whatever */
    /* plus the above stuff */
}
```

This makes it so that any text (e.g. whitespace) that appears inside the container is zero-sized, unless it appears inside the divs you are stacking next to each other, in which case it reverts back to `12px`. As I said, a pretty bad hack. But it works.

---

The more general solution is the new [flexbox proposal](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/), but that is still under heavy revision: there are two outdated versions implemented in various browsers, with the latest one not being implemented in any as of today (2012-05-15). If you know your exact environment, though, this might be a good solution.

Comment: the problem is that I need N divs. I also tried inline-block. I think I need to use javascript

Comment: You could adjust the `width` values using JavaScript.

Comment: I am using it now but space between divs is a big problem

Answer (score 0):

For two divs, just do ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zBSZK/)):

```
div
{
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}
```

For three, do ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zBSZK/1/)):

```
div
{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants a fixed margin between them, which complicates matters.

Comment: The margin between them would be fixed in the above scenario? :)

Comment: I have N divs. it's ok for 2, or 3 divs

Comment: Yes, but the percentage doesn't apply to the margin, right?  So If you had a margin of 10px, you would end up with 99% + 20px in your second example, which would run over your page width.

Comment: @NickSanders for N divs, that's possible in JQuery, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zBSZK/2/

Comment: @JeffB Yeah it's the only problem at this moment

Comment: @mattytommo I have done like this but space between them isn't easy to implement

Comment: @NickSanders it just requires a bit more maths :) check http://jsfiddle.net/zBSZK/3/ and if you want to increase the margin (it needs to be a percentage), then you'll need to change the CSS in that fiddle, then the declaration of `var margin = $("div").length * 1` change the times by 1 to be the new value of the margin you have put in the CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need an arbitrary number of divs, you have two options:

1. If the number is determined by the server (value is coming from a database or a session or whatever), you can generate appropriate CSS on the **server side**. This solution is preferable.
2. If not, you need JavaScript to calculate the viewport's width, and assign width values accordingly to your divs.

Comment: I can use both client & server sides but still, the space between two divs is complicated

Answer (score 0):

The same thing could be achieved using CSS3 Flexible Box Style Layout with very less coding. Well it depends upon the browser you are planning to support.

*Now Flexible box layout is supported only in webkit engines & mozilla*

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as an answer because I guess it's valid and may serve you well. 960.gs and bootstrap both provide scaffolding for layouts identical to what you want.  960.gs is just layout but if bootstrap suits you, you can customize it on their site to just get the bits that deal with layout.  One caveat for bootstrap, I haven't found a way to remove the left margin on the div columns.  960.gs includes `alpha` and `omega` classes that set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to 0 respectivley.  I had to add these to bootstrap when I used it.

Using one of those scaffoldings will save you a lot of time and effort.  If you have to hand your code off to somebody else later or even just have somebody else working on it with you, using a scaffolding will help them work with your code too.